# When setTimeRange is large and bucketByTime is short in DataReadRequest of Google fit history Api, getting error "gms.common.api.ApiException: 5022"

Tags: java, android, google-fit

I am trying to read all data from the Google fitness store, but when the "setTimeRange" is large ie: i am trying to get all data and the "bucketByTime" is in small range ie: bucketByTime(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES), I am getting the exception "**There was an error reading data from Google Fit
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 5022: Cannot bucket into more than 86400 intervals.**"

```
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date now = new Date();
            cal.setTime(now);
            long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
            calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

            DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE)
            .read(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
            .read(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_OXYGEN_SATURATION)
            .bucketByTime(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .build();
```

How can I get all data in the google fitness store??

Comment: Query data on my end looks fine. Try to check the actual value you sent, as it may look like the error 5002 status code denotes that the timestamp in the query is bad. This may be due to a bad time specified in the request or bad system time.

Comment: Thank you ilovesyntax for you reply. If i try to read one year data, i will get the same response ie.   Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        long endTime=calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
        long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();   and the error i get is 5022 and not 5002